# Do field enchantments stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Do field enchantments, such as cards that say "opponent puts the top two cards of their library into their graveyard", stack with multiple iterations of it on my field? The specific example I'll use is what happened last night:

My friend had played two copies of [Drowned Secrets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDrowned%20Secrets%5d) and was basically milling me out for 4 cards every time he played a blue spell. I let it play out, but I would like to know what the legality of it is going forward. I'm aware of the Legendary card rule, but we're just getting into Magic, and we're learning the rules as we go along.

Comment: Each will trigger. Each will mill 2 even it resolves, for a total of 4

Comment: As a rule of thumb, unless specifically stated, the interaction between cards is minimal. They are not aware of each others' existence, and they just do their own thing. Some exceptions are things like the legend rule, or auras caring about the creature they enchant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes; each Drowned Secrets on the battlefield will trigger when the controller casts a blue spell. It is no different than 2 unrelated abilities both triggering upon the same event.

For example, if you had both a [Drowned Secrets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDrowned%20Secrets%5d) and a [Merrow Levitator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMerrow%20Levitator%5d) on the battlefield and you cast a blue spell, both abilities would trigger. It is no different with 2 separate Drowned Secrets.

Other abilities besides triggered abilities stack as well; such as if you had 2 copies of [Honor of the Pure](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHonor%20of%20the%20Pure%5d) on the battlefield. In that case, White creatures you control would get a total of +2/+2.