# Do you get a counter for each Tempered Sliver on the battlefield

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I'm building my first sliver deck.

If I have two [Tempered Slivers](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=464132) on the battle field and a Sliver I control deals damage to a player, would it get one +1/+1 counter or two.

My gut is telling me it would be just the one.

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/49390/do-field-enchantments-stack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The sliver in case would, in fact, get 2 +1/+1 counters.**

---

This is because of rule 113.2c, which I quote, with the relevant bit emphasized:

> 113.2c An object may have multiple abilities. If the object is represented by a card, then aside from certain defined abilities that may be strung together on a single line (see rule 702, “Keyword Abilities”), each paragraph break in a card’s text marks a separate ability. If the object is not represented by a card, the effect that created it may have given it multiple abilities. An object may also be granted additional abilities by a spell or ability. **If an object has multiple instances of the same ability, each instance functions independently**. This may or may not produce more effects than a single instance; refer to the specific ability for more information.

The part in bold font means that your slivers (including your Tempered Slivers) have, besides their other abilities, two instances of

> "Whenever this creature deals combat damage to a player, put a +1/+1 counter on it".

Both instances will trigger independently, giving your slivers two +1/+1 counters.

Comment: Happy days, I'll add the 4 of them in then!

Comment: @Phil3992 I can guarantee you'll have a lot of fun with Sliver decks. I can also guarantee your friends will not. (Jokes aside, it's a pretty fun deck to play with when you have a bunch of big creatures with trample, haste, flying, and a couple +1/+1 counters and buffs).

Comment: With Bonescythe Sliver or Fury Sliver you can have them getting twice as many +1/+1 counters per turn.